# Why am I getting a Missing sentinel warning?

Tags: c++, operating-system, exec, fork

Base code:

```
        char *args[3] = {NULL};
        args[0] = "ls";
        args[1] = "-l";
        args[2] = NULL;
```

Why would :

```
        int execution = execlp("ls", args[0], args[1], NULL);
```

Cause no warning, and :

```
        int execution = execlp("ls", args[0], args[1], args[2]);
```

Cause a warning: *missing sentinel in function call?*

Note: I understand that both are the same but im just curious as to why one cause a warning and not the other one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because [`The list of arguments must be terminated by a NULL pointer`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execlp). Even though `args[2]` happens to be `NULL` in your case, the compiler doesn't have that insight (nor should it, if you ask me).

What if someone comes along and changes `args[2]` to something else, not knowing it's used as a sentinel?

Comment: "What if someone comes along and changes args[2] to something else, not knowing it's used as a sentinel?" - that's what static analysis is for, if you ask me.

Comment: @H2CO3 maybe, but I've seen many cases where warnings get ignored alltogether. I'd rather play it safe, but that's just me. It's subjective whether the diagnosis is useful or not, I for one think it is.

Comment: Yes, here the *compiler is right but this is a false positive.* Strange enough.

Answer (score 0):

Because the compiler ain't intelligent.

It expects the sentinel to be a literal `0` or `NULL` (which is really just `0` or `(void *)0`), and anything else generates the warning. If the compiler was smarter and it performed some more static analysis on the code, it could have concluded that `args[2]` is indeed a constant 0, so no warning is needed, but apparently it couldn't.